# Whack a mole - setButton in a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i made a game similar to whack a mole. Instead of a mole you have to click on a "x".
I want to change the position of the "x" randomly but i have the following error "error: cannot find symbol method getButton1()"
(zufall means random on german)

Thread zufallsXThread = new Thread() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (fail > 3) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int zufall = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;

                        if (zufall == 1) {
                            this.getButton1().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 2) {
                            this.getButton2().post("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 3) {
                            this.getButton3().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 4) {
                            this.getButton4().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 5) {
                            this.getButton5().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 6) {
                            this.getButton6().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 7) {
                            this.getButton7().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 8) {
                            this.getButton8().setText("x");
                        } else if (zufall == 9) {
                            this.getButton9().setText("x");
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Where is `getButton1()` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `this` keyword from the method calling .

```
if (zufall == 1) {
     getButton1().setText("x");
 }
```

and change for all inside the run method.

Comment: To explain-  this in that context refers to the immediate parent class-  the Runnable.  Obviously the function isn't on the Runnable, so it isn't found via this.